# Create nested foreach over the elements of an array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I need to create nested `foreach` loops between them as there are elements of an array.

example:

This is the array starting

```
print_r($container);



Array
(
    [list1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id_topic] => 45
                    [id_topicGroup] => 44
                    [topic] => topic1 di 44
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id_topic] => 46
                    [id_topicGroup] => 44
                    [topic] => topic2 di 44
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id_topic] => 47
                    [id_topicGroup] => 44
                    [topic] => topic3 di 44
                )

        )

    [list2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id_topic] => 48
                    [id_topicGroup] => 45
                    [topic] => topic1 di 45
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id_topic] => 49
                    [id_topicGroup] => 45
                    [topic] => topic2 di 45
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id_topic] => 50
                    [id_topicGroup] => 45
                    [topic] => topic3 di 45
                )

        )

)
```

This is the processing for printing the elements for this case

```
foreach($container)['list1'] as $el_lista1) {
                foreach($container)['list2'] as $el_lista2) {
                    echo $el_lista1 . " " . $el_lista2 . "<br>\n";
                }                
            }
```

This is the output

```
topic1 di 44 topic1 di 45

topic1 di 44 topic2 di 45

topic1 di 44 topic3 di 45

topic2 di 44 topic1 di 45

topic2 di 44 topic2 di 45

topic2 di 44 topic3 di 45

topic3 di 44 topic1 di 45

topic3 di 44 topic2 di 45

topic3 di 44 topic3 di 45
```

But the problem is that it has to manage an unlimited number of lists and forums on the inside as I do?

I think I need to create a number of internal `foreach` loops among them according to the number of lists such as these.  Can you do this?

Comment: So You want all possible combinations of topics from all lists?

Comment: This is a job for recursion.

Comment: You're approaching the recursion wrong, should be something like foreach ($container as $list){ foreach ($list as $items) { ....  } }

Comment: It has been suggested that the syntax of the foreach code may be incorrect - however a 3rd party edit to the question code is not the appropriate way of dealing with that - once we start functionally modifying the question, we can end up adding or removing problems.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use [RecursiveArrayIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php)

```
<?php
$arr=Array
(
    "list1" => Array
        (
            "0" => Array
                (
                    "id_topic" => 45,
                    "id_topicGroup" => 44,
                    "topic" => "topic1 di 44"
                ),

            "1" => Array
                (
                    "id_topic" => 46,
                    "id_topicGroup" => 44,
                    "topic" => "topic2 di 44",
                ),
            "2" => Array
                (
                    "id_topic" => 47,
                    "id_topicGroup" => 44,
                    "topic" => "topic3 di 44",
                )

        ),

    "list2" => Array
        (
            "0" => Array
                (
                    "id_topic" => 48,
                    "id_topicGroup" => 45,
                    "topic" => "topic1 di 45"
                ),

            "1" => Array
                (
                    "id_topic" => 49,
                    "id_topicGroup" => 45,
                    "topic" => "topic2 di 45",
                ),

            "2" => Array
                (
                    "id_topic" => 50,
                    "id_topicGroup" => 45,
                    "topic" => "topic3 di 45"
                )

        )

);

$iterator = new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr); 
iterator_apply($iterator, 'traverseStructure', array($iterator)); 

// from php manual

function traverseStructure($iterator) { 

    while ( $iterator -> valid() ) { 

        if ( $iterator -> hasChildren() ) { 

            traverseStructure($iterator -> getChildren()); 

        } 
        else { 
            echo $iterator -> key() . ' : ' . $iterator -> current() .'<br>';    
        } 

        $iterator -> next(); 
    } 
}
```

---

```
//print according to your need
```

output:

```
id_topic : 45
id_topicGroup : 44
topic : topic1 di 44
id_topic : 46
id_topicGroup : 44
topic : topic2 di 44
id_topic : 47
id_topicGroup : 44
topic : topic3 di 44
id_topic : 48
id_topicGroup : 45
topic : topic1 di 45
id_topic : 49
id_topicGroup : 45
topic : topic2 di 45
id_topic : 50
id_topicGroup : 45
topic : topic3 di 45
```